# Log4j2 memory leak

Tags: java, log4j2

I've searched everywhere for a solution to this, and now I'm beginning to wonder whether it's really an issue.

I'm introducing `log4j2` as the logger into my application and when I do that, on a reload, undeploy or stop of the Tomcat server 8.5.24, a memory leak is left, which only happens once I introduce the logger into the code.

My dependencies in `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.0</version>
</dependency>
```

My `WebServlet`:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

@WebServlet(name = "Servlet", urlPatterns = {"/servlet"}, loadOnStartup = 1)
public class Servlet extends HttpServlet {

    private final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Servlet.class);

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        logger.info("doGet");

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.print("Servlet loaded");
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }

}
```

My `log4j2.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d %p %c %m%n" />
        </Console>
        <File name="File" bufferedIO="true" fileName="logs/log4j2-file-sync-${date:HH:MM:ss.SSS}.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d %p %c %m%n" />
        </File>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="all" includeLocation="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
            <AppenderRef ref="File" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
The following web applications were stopped (reloaded, undeployed), but their
classes from previous runs are still loaded in memory, thus causing a memory
leak (use a profiler to confirm):
/myapp
```

Comment: Tomcat had classloader memoty leak problem for quite some time. On redeploys it would not unload all the classes loaded from the war.

Comment: Is there a way around it though?  In a production environment, I would have to restart the server on every deployment update, or at least every n redploys.  Perhaps I should be using another Server?

Comment: Again I am not sure if newer version of Tomcat work but I remember we had to restart Tomcat on every new deployment. That was 6-7 years ago.

Comment: Im using 8.5.24 which is the latest pre-beta http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html

Comment: Same recommendation here. Always restart tomcat if you want be free of leak problems. There is even scripts over the internet that do it automagically. search for it :) And then configure your CI tools to deploy and restart using such script.

Comment: @JorgeCampos Should I be using a different Web Server?

Comment: I don't think you need to change the server... is far to easy to use such script rather than the cons of using another server container...

Comment: If this issue can be reproduced with the latest version of Log4j2, please raise it on the Log4j2 JIRA issue tracker. Be sure to give all details like Tomcat version etc. In the description please mention the exact steps to reproduce the issue. Ideally provide a minimal web app that can be used to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @RemkoPopma It sounds more like a problem with Tomcat that Log4j2.

Comment: @RemkoPopma done: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-2167

Comment: Ralph suggested on the JIRA ticket to add the log4j-web dependency. Can you try that?

Comment: @RemkoPopma That did it.  Where in the documentation does it tell you to add that! :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question thanks to the advice of @RemkoPopma from the comments and @RalphGoers from the Tomcat JIRA board.

I only needed the following dependency in my `pom.xml` which also imports the `core` and `api` and which handles proper shutdown of the Log4J2.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The specific documentation for this dependency can be found

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/webapp.html